# For the apps Built using create-react-app command, does it optimize css files also for production build?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface

I have used Bootstrap for my react project, for simple HTML landing pages I used purgeCSS, however in react (cra template) does the production build remove unused CSS also?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't. You might need to do something like https://survivejs.com/webpack/styling/eliminating-unused-css/

Answer (score 0):

The commented code goes away but not unused css.